# Frequent uploading failures, corrupted files

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

I have encountered the following problem on wordpress (self hosted). 80% of the pictures I upload fail, either by not crunching (and mentioning an HTTP error), or by displaying the following error:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd-png: fatal libpng error: IDAT: CRC error in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd-png error: setjmp returns error condition in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Passed data is not in 'PNG' format in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Couldn't create GD Image Stream out of Data in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd-png: fatal libpng error: IDAT: CRC error in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd-png error: setjmp returns error condition in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Passed data is not in 'PNG' format in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Couldn't create GD Image Stream out of Data in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd-png: fatal libpng error: IDAT: CRC error in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd-png error: setjmp returns error condition in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Passed data is not in 'PNG' format in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Couldn't create GD Image Stream out of Data in /home/content/60/4915360/html/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php on line 258
```

---

On top of that, if the picture is a tad too big (~400k is ok, not 900k), it will upload but with a 80% chance of being corrupted (i.e. chunks of inverted/swapped/displaced colors). It might not be related to wordpress, as I observed this corruption thing on other services too (deviantart, shownd). I used to think it was because of these services bad quality, but I'm starting to suspect an issue with my connexion (I am using my university's network).

Would you have an idea of what could cause these problems?

Answer (score 0):

Which method are you using to upload the graphics? I have not encountered the error you are showing, but I do sometimes get crashes and failed uploads when using the uploader that is inside Wordpress.

Have you tried using an FTP program to upload the files? I do that when I encounter failed uploads from inside Wordpress.

If all else fails, you could backup your site and reinstall Wordpress. (I have also done this and got better results.)